# How to toggle hide and show child elements in tree layout?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here is my html code which requires some update like span or something which can let it hide all child elements to display children on click only for individual parent.

how can I add toggle span and javascript to make it show on click only specific child of each parent not all of them at once.

i am too beginner with javascript so no idea how can this be done please help me out how can i resolve this issue it will save my life. Thanks a lot

```
<div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-8" id="Permission">
<ul id="Div1" class="tree">
  <li class="has">
     <input type="checkbox" name="Dashboard" value="yes"> Dashboard  
     <ul> </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="Div2" class="tree">
  <li class="has" "="">
     <input type="checkbox" name="Master" value="yes"> Master  
     <ul>
        <li>
           <input type="checkbox" id="Upper1  name=" menus-accesscontrol[9]"="" value="9"> AccessControl 
           <ul id="Parent1">
              <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="Menus-User[3]" value="3"> User 
                 <ul class="childs">
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="UserAllowCreate" value="0"> Allow Create</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="UserAllowDelete" value="0"> Allow Delete </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="UserAllowEdit" value="0"> Allow Edit </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="UserAllowView" value="0"> Allow View </li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="Menus-Menu[6]" value="6"> Menu 
                 <ul class="childs">
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="MenuAllowCreate" value="0"> Allow Create</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="MenuAllowDelete" value="0"> Allow Delete </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="MenuAllowEdit" value="0"> Allow Edit </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="MenuAllowView" value="0"> Allow View </li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="Menus-Group[23]" value="23"> Group 
                 <ul class="childs">
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="GroupAllowCreate" value="0"> Allow Create</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="GroupAllowDelete" value="0"> Allow Delete </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="GroupAllowEdit" value="0"> Allow Edit </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="GroupAllowView" value="0"> Allow View </li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
        <li class="has parentCheckBox">
           <input type="checkbox" name="Menus-CustomerMaster[2]" value="2"> CustomerMaster 
           <ul class="childs">
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="CustomerMasterAllowCreate" value="0"> Allow Create</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="CustomerMasterAllowDelete" value="0"> Allow Delete</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="CustomerMasterAllowEdit" value="0"> Allow Edit</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="CustomerMasterAllowView" value="0"> Allow View</li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        
        </li> 
     </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <ul id="Div3" class="tree">
  <li class="has" "="">
     <input type="checkbox" name="Inventory" value="yes"> Inventory  
     <ul>
        <li class="has parentCheckBox">
           <input type="checkbox" name="Menus-UserRecharge[8]" value="8"> UserRecharge 
           <ul class="childs">
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="UserRechargeAllowCreate" value="0"> Allow Create</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="UserRechargeAllowDelete" value="0"> Allow Delete</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="UserRechargeAllowEdit" value="0"> Allow Edit</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="UserRechargeAllowView" value="0"> Allow View</li>
           </ul>
        <li class="has parentCheckBox">
           <input type="checkbox" name="Menus-SupplierInventory[43]" value="43"> SupplierInventory 
           <ul class="childs">
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="SupplierInventoryAllowCreate" value="0"> Allow Create</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="SupplierInventoryAllowDelete" value="0"> Allow Delete</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="SupplierInventoryAllowEdit" value="0"> Allow Edit</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="SupplierInventoryAllowView" value="0"> Allow View</li>
           </ul>
        <li>
           <input type="checkbox" id="Upper2  name=" menus-report[30]"="" value="30"> Report 
           <ul id="Parent2">
              <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="Menus-CustomerException[31]" value="31"> CustomerException 
                 <ul class="childs">
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="CustomerExceptionAllowCreate" value="0"> Allow Create</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="CustomerExceptionAllowDelete" value="0"> Allow Delete </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="CustomerExceptionAllowEdit" value="0"> Allow Edit </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="CustomerExceptionAllowView" value="0"> Allow View </li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="Menus-SuplierException[33]" value="33"> SuplierException 
                 <ul class="childs">
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="SuplierExceptionAllowCreate" value="0"> Allow Create</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="SuplierExceptionAllowDelete" value="0"> Allow Delete </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="SuplierExceptionAllowEdit" value="0"> Allow Edit </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="SuplierExceptionAllowView" value="0"> Allow View </li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="Menus-SupplierReport[34]" value="34"> SupplierReport 
                 <ul class="childs">
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="SupplierReportAllowCreate" value="0"> Allow Create</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="SupplierReportAllowDelete" value="0"> Allow Delete </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="SupplierReportAllowEdit" value="0"> Allow Edit </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="SupplierReportAllowView" value="0"> Allow View </li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="Menus-SenderSupplierSummary[35]" value="35"> SenderSupplierSummary 
                 <ul class="childs">
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="SenderSupplierSummaryAllowCreate" value="0"> Allow Create</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="SenderSupplierSummaryAllowDelete" value="0"> Allow Delete </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="SenderSupplierSummaryAllowEdit" value="0"> Allow Edit </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="SenderSupplierSummaryAllowView" value="0"> Allow View </li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="Menus-MonthlySale[39]" value="39"> MonthlySale 
                 <ul class="childs">
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="MonthlySaleAllowCreate" value="0"> Allow Create</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="MonthlySaleAllowDelete" value="0"> Allow Delete </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="MonthlySaleAllowEdit" value="0"> Allow Edit </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="MonthlySaleAllowView" value="0"> Allow View </li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        </li> </li> </li> </li> </li> </li> </li> </li> </li> </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="Div4" class="tree">
  <li class="has" "="">
     <input type="checkbox" name="Invoice" value="yes"> Invoice  
     <ul>
        <li class="has parentCheckBox">
           <input type="checkbox" name="Menus-CustomerInvoice[44]" value="44"> CustomerInvoice 
           <ul class="childs">
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="CustomerInvoiceAllowCreate" value="0"> Allow Create</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="CustomerInvoiceAllowDelete" value="0"> Allow Delete</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="CustomerInvoiceAllowEdit" value="0"> Allow Edit</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="CustomerInvoiceAllowView" value="0"> Allow View</li>
           </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="Div5" class="tree">
  <li class="has" "="">
     <input type="checkbox" name="Contract Management" value="yes"> Contract Management  
     <ul>
        <li class="has parentCheckBox">
           <input type="checkbox" name="Menus-Configuration[45]" value="45"> Configuration 
           <ul class="childs">
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="ConfigurationAllowCreate" value="0"> Allow Create</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="ConfigurationAllowDelete" value="0"> Allow Delete</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="ConfigurationAllowEdit" value="0"> Allow Edit</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="ConfigurationAllowView" value="0"> Allow View</li>
           </ul>
        <li class="has parentCheckBox">
           <input type="checkbox" name="Menus-Contract[47]" value="47"> Contract 
           <ul class="childs">
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="ContractAllowCreate" value="0"> Allow Create</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="ContractAllowDelete" value="0"> Allow Delete</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="ContractAllowEdit" value="0"> Allow Edit</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="ContractAllowView" value="0"> Allow View</li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: You are having some problems in your html. `class="has" "=""` and `id="Upper1  name=" menus-accesscontrol[9]"=""` is not valid. please fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'toggleClass' in jQuery though there are other ways base on your needs. But you can check this basic example so that you can have an idea.

```
$(".root").on("click", function(){
    $(this).find("ul").toggleClass("hide-children");
  })
```

Sample 1 Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nq5ecbLu/1/

Sample 2 Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mt10aeg7/

Comment: While I understand your answer I don't believe it would solve the op's problems, (Also it's not clear what he wants)

Comment: well it could resolve but i have problem here it have multiple children like parent children then children children so how will this work for them in toggle.

Comment: @kamranhassan, you can check for Sample 2 Fiddle. It has multiple nested parent.